# Jquery external file not working with with Google Chrome

Tags: jquery

Path is correct.This code is working in Firefox but not in Google Chrome.

```
<script src="jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="bluecheeze.js"></script>
```

Code in external file as follows:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
 alert("hello");
 });
```

I have also tried using:

```
 <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.2.1.min.js">
 </script>
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ran Ccleaner and it resolved the issue.

Comment: For anyone else - open developer console or use incognito tab and then reload page - Chrome do not always reload scripts :) For feature, when You make changes in html, css or js, open developer console in chrome and then reload page. I also lost and hour to know what is going on in Chrome :)

Answer (score 1):

Give this a shot. Maybe chrome does not like your formatting. Also make sure it is at the top of your code in your `<head>` tag.

```
  <script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js"
  integrity="sha256-DZAnKJ/6XZ9si04Hgrsxu/8s717jcIzLy3oi35EouyE="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Also try this in your js file:

```
window.onload = function() {
//your code
}
```

Why? If your jQuery code is not working in Chrome, Safari, Andriod or other browsers, it might be because the images and banners are not fully loaded only using the “document ready function”. To solve this problem use “window onload” function to ensure ALL data is fully loaded before your jQuery code is executed. (window onload can be used inside the document ready function)

Taken from [Here](http://www.lets-develop.com/html5-html-css-css3-php-wordpress-jquery-javascript-photoshop-illustrator-flash-tutorial/java-script-jquery-j-query-javascript-programming/jquery-not-working-in-chrome-jquery-not-loading/)

Comment: Still no luck! :(

Comment: :( did you try the window.onload?

Comment: @AndrewLeonardi - js should work. onload doesn't have nothing to do with it. onload You use when some scripts needs to be executed after DOM is fully loaded but it doesn't change that "document ready function" should work.

Comment: Could a virus affect Chrome and not Firefox? Even if I console.log(2) it doesn't appear in Chrome but appears in Firefox

Comment: That is very odd. I doubt its a virus. Somehow Chrome is not finding your js file.

Comment: Thanks, issue resolved, I ran CCleaner, everything is working.

Comment: @ticktock - that's why I tell You to open developer console or use incognito tab and then reload page - Chrome do not always reload scripts :) For feature, when You make changes in html, css or js, open developer console in chrome and then reload page. I also lost and hour to know what is going on in Chrome :)

Comment: I did exactly that, I still don't know what the issue was but Ccleaner resolves issues so I took a chance and it worked, thanks for your help Michael

Answer (score 0):

Chrome from sometime have strange behavior - it only reload scripts like .js, .css when developer console is open - or in incognito mode.

Maybe try to use:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery_version.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="your_file.js"></script>
```

of course when Your HTML is in that same directory.

Comment: Still no luck adding type="text/javascript"

Comment: Then I don't know. I just create files like this and it's work for me :) Did You include this <script> just before </body> closing tag ?

Comment: I added it to the head section. my version of chrome Version 57.14.2987.98

Comment: Add it just before </body> JS scripts should be at the end of body tag, when all HTML is loaded. In <head> you put css scripts.